# Regex that validates Active Directory default password complexity

Tags: regex, active-directory, passwords

I have a list of passwords that I need to examine and determine if they meet the default 3 of 4 rule for AD.

Rule is contain 3 of the 4 following requirements:
lower case character (a-z)
upper case character (A-Z)
numeric (0-9)
special character ( !@#$%^&*()_+= )

I am still learning Regex.  I know how to select only those that meet any one character case, but I am not sure how to do 3 of 4.

As a side note, the AD Complexity has two more subtleties that are important (but out of scope of the original question).

It is really 3 of 5.  The fifth is Unicode character.  Be nice to update the Regex with that.

The other is you cannot have the sAMAccountName value in whole in the password (case insensitive), nor if you split the displayName value into tokens split upon space, comma, dash, underscore, pound, pipe and something else those tokens (3 chars and longer) cannot be in whole in the password, case insensitive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you really want one big regex it would be something like this:

```
(?=^.{8,255}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*
```

Note that it also enforces password length to be between 8 and 255 characters.  You can change the "{8,255}" portion in the first section to adjust the length requirements.  It is also worth noting that this is working for me in a standard ASP.NET [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx) control.

Matches: "Passw0rd" "passW@rd" "1B2a345@#$%"

Non-Matches: "123123123" "Password" "asdf&amp;"

[Source](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=887) (Matthew Hazzard via RegExLib.com)

Comment: Just testing this approach brings me to find a case that 't3st33#3' shows up as valid, but 't3st33#33' doesn't.

Comment: @geoffc I ran a quick test using an [online validator](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=887) and found the correct results for 't3st33#3' (valid), 't3st33#33' (valid), and 'password1' (invalid).  Maybe check your regex options and make sure it is evaluating for matches with **case sensitivity enabled**.

Comment: Actually that is a good point!  Maybe it was case sensitivity!  I figured that out when I used the 4 separate regex approach.

Comment: instead of using `[^A-Za-z0-9]` (no alfanumeric) you should use the symbol charset `[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=]`. Be careful with scaped characters.

Comment: People should know that while this may have received lots of upvotes, it's not great. The 5 character complexity classes used by AD are defined in terms of unicode, while this answer gives a regex that only supports ASCII text passwords. So, users outside the USA are likely to find that this regex rejects their passwords, despite the fact that real AD accepts it. Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be all one big regex?  You could do 4 regexes, each checking one thing and then make sure 3 of the 4 are matches.  That would be easier, less error prone and more maintainable.

Comment: Well one big regex would be easier to use.  I have yet to decide on the tool I will use it in.  Leaning towards Perl, but actually will probably do it in Novell Identity Manager in DirXML Script, since it is in an IDM system already.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to build up the regular expression like this:

```
rule = [ "[a-z]", "[A-Z]", "[0-9]", "[!@#$%\^\&\(\)\+=]" ]

regex = ""
first = true
for a in 0..3:
  for b in 0..3:
    if a == b: continue
    for c in 0..3:
      if a == c or b == c: continue
      if not first:
        regex += "|"
      regex += "(" + rule[a] + ".*" + rule[b] + ".*" + rule[c] + ")"
      first = false
```

I'm not sure if I escaped the special characters correctly. It's kind of dependant on the language/toolkit you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the [@saul-dolgin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3166778/1170950) answer to exactly match with the valid charset specified in the question (not a a non-alfanumeric character `[^A-Za-z0-9]`):

```
(?=^[A-Za-z\d!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=]{8,20}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=]))^.*
```

Microsoft forces passwords to have only characters from their list.
I also changed the Maximum lenght to 20.

Comment: I'm quite sure "characters from their list" include all characters, including spaces, comma's etc...  
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I mean that other symbols not listed fit in `[^A-Za-z0-9]` pattern. i.e euro, pound, yen...