# How to validate password policy with default windows server 2008 condition

Tags: powershell

how to validate default password policy when we adding new user in local user account creation using `net user /add $username $password`

I have validated the username existence with below command

```
$CheckUser=net user $UserName
if($CheckUser){
    Write-OutPut "Username is already exists"
}
```

How would I check the password with default windows server password policy?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to just try the password and trap the error, you could check the conditions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx fairly easily, but i think it is probably unnecessary. Whats the reasoning behind wanting to do this?

Comment: You can use [regex to validate the password strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774569/regex-that-validates-active-directory-default-password-complexity) or [use a function](http://www.checkyourlogs.net/?p=38333) to check it.

Comment: Thank you its done